# How to make a checkbox into a button?

Tags: html, forms, input, get

Here is the code. There is a search bar where a user can put in a topic then select a button that shows different categories.

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input placeholder="Search" name="search" aria-label="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="S" class="searchButton" name="submit-request"/>
    <div class="buttons" style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="button" class="spec" name="category1" value="category1">
            <input type="button" class="spec" name="category2" value="category2">
            <input type="button" class="spec" name="category3" value="category3">
            <input type="button" class="spec" name="category4" value="category4">
            <input type="button" class="spec" name="category5" value="category5">
    </div>
</form>
```

This search form works perfectly fine with checkboxes. What should I do as an alternative? Is there a way I can style the checkboxes as buttons. If they are checkboxes how can I make it so that a user can only pick one category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use radio buttons.
Show name for radio with label.
To style a radio button, hide it, and add pseudo element.

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` is it's own tag.

```
<button class="spec" name="category5">category5</button>
```

If you wanted to use CSS (you didn't tag it in your post), you can try this:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_form_button

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="navigation">
            <input type="checkbox" class="navigation__checkbox" id="**navi-toggle**">

            <label for="**navi-toggle**" class="navigation__button">
                <span class="navigation__icon">&nbsp;</span>
            </label>
</div>

.navigation {
    &__checkbox {
        display: none;
    }

    &__button{
        background-color: $color-white;
        height: 7rem;
        width: 7rem;
    }
```

You say that you want to be able to still use checkbox as that is what functions... Well you could do so and use a label that is linked to that checkbox, and then simply style your label as your button.

Comment: Please select an answer to help users with the same issue find the solution.